# Complexity of two cumulative sum (cumsum) functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, complexity-theory, ghci, cumulative-sum

Consider the following two cumulative sum (cumsum) functions:

```
cumsum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
cumsum [] = []
cumsum [x] = [x]
cumsum (x:y:ys) = x : (cumsum $ (x+y) : ys)
```

and

```
cumsum' :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
cumsum' x = [sum $ take k x | k <- [1..length x]]
```

Of course, I prefer the definition of `cumsum` to that of `cumsum'` and I understand that the former has linear complexity.

But just why does `cumsum'` also have linear complexity? `take` itself has linear complexity in the length of its argument and `k` runs from `1` to `length x`. **Therefore I'd have expected quadratic complexity for** `cumsum'`.

Moreover, the constant of `cumsum'` is lower than that of `cumsum`. Is that due to the recursive list appending of the latter?

**NOTE**: welcoming any smart definition of a cumulative sum.

**EDIT**: I'm measuring execution times using (after enabling `:set +s` in GHCi):

```
last $ cumsum [1..n]
```

Comment: I suspect that you are mistaken in your measurements - I can't see how `cumsum'` could have linear complexity.

Comment: FWIW, `scanl (+) 0`

Comment: I just measured it myself and it's definitely quadratic. Did you do something a bit too lazy to avoid getting the output printed out?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I measured it with `last $ cumsum' [1..n]`

Comment: That is indeed a bit too lazy. It won't compute the intermediate sums. I used `max` rather than `last`.

Comment: `\x -> [take k x | k <- [1..length x]]` is `tail . inits`, except the latter doesn't compute the length, and doesn't start over to produce each sublist. Your function is `map sum . tail . inits`

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Many thanks, I tried with `maximum` and, indeed, I now observe quadratic complexity. In a sense I'm glad because this made me wary of measurement, cheers! A follow-up question is then: how is laziness implemented in `last`?

Comment: Nothing to do with `last` itself, but Haskell laziness in general. `last` only inspects the structure of the list as that's all it needs to do, so the individual elements won't be forced and all but the final element will be just thrown away. Then the return value (i.e. the final element) is forced to print it out.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Okay I can (sort of) live with the fact that laziness implies that not all elements are _forced out_ for now (although they all still need to be computed). Could you just wrap your comment regarding the laziness of `last` in the time measurement in a short answer that I can accept? This may help others, thx

Comment: @luqui Or just `scanl1 (+)`.

Comment: @okiharaherbst: they actually don't still need to be computed, since in your second definition, no list element's computation depends on that of any other list element. So haskell will only actually evaluate `sum $ take (length x) x`

Comment: @genisage Right, every now and then I forget about laziness in Haskell. So I should be more cautious with my time measurements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a measurement error caused by laziness.

Every value in Haskell is lazy: it isn't evaluated until necessary. This includes sub-structure of values - so for example when we see a pattern (`x:xs`) this only forces evaluation of the list far enough to identify that the list is non-empty, but it doesn't force the head `x` or the tail `xs`.

The definition of `last` is something like:

```
last [x] = x
last (x:xs) = last xs
```

So when `last` is applied to the result of `cumsum'`, it inspects the list comprehension recursively, but only enough to track down the last entry. It doesn't force any of the entries, but it does return the last one.

When this last entry is printed in ghci or whatever, then it is forced which takes linear time as expected. But the other entries are never calculated so we don't see the "expected" quadratic behaviour.

Using `maximum` instead of `last` does demonstrate that `cumnorm'` is quadratic whereas `cumnorm` is linear.

[Note: this explanation is somewhat hand-wavy: really evaluation is entirely driven by what's needed for the final result, so even `last` is only evaluted at all because its result is needed. Search for things like "Haskell evaluation order" and "Weak Head Normal Form" to get a more precise explanation.]